# Pygame - Rect collision by side

Tags: python, pygame, collision

How can I find if two rects collide on a certain side? (e.g. rect1.rect.top, rect2.rect.bottom) I've tried `rect1.rect.colliderect(rect2)` and `pygame.sprite.collide_rect(rect1, rect2)`, but they don't find the individual side collisions.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I found the answer. `if rect1.rect.bottom >= rect2.rect.top and rect1.rect.bottom <= rect2.rect.bottom:`